# CRC32 Calculation for Zero Filled Buffer/File

Tags: algorithm, crc, crc32

If I want to calculate the CRC32 value for a large number of consecutive zero bytes, is there a constant time formula I can use given the length of the run of zeros? For example, if I know I have 1000 bytes all filled with zeros, is there a way to avoid a loop with 1000 iterations (just an example, actual number of zeros is unbounded for the sake of this question)?

Comment: Yes, there is.  Do you know how polynomials over GF(2) work?

Comment: One method of order log(number of zeroes) is described in Mark Adler's crc32_combine in the zlib source. It can be generalized to other CRC algorithms.

Comment: @rcgldr for **n** zero bytes, the CRC is **initial_value*(x^8n) mod poly**.  You can calculate **x^8n mod poly** using exponentiation by squaring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring   ... but it's not going to do the OP any good if I say that when he doesn't know what it means.

Comment: @MattTimmermans - I deleted my prior comment. The OP asked for a constant time "formula", which is possible if `n` is a constant.

Comment: @rcgldr,  **n** doesn't have to be constant.  It just has to be bounded.  If **n > 2^32**, then you can reduce it mod **2^32-1**, because the pattern of CRCs with **n** zeros repeats with that period.  Under the usual assumption that you can do arithmetic on **n** in constant time, then, exponentiation by squaring takes at most 32 steps, i.e., can be done in constant time.  OK, that assumption is a bit of a joke in this context, but for real practical purposes it's constant time unless the function takes **n** as a bignum.   If **n** is a bignum then it's **O(log n)** just for the modulus.

Comment: @MattTimmermans - Some implementations of this could be O(log2(n)) (possibly fewer than 32 steps) versus O(1), even though in this case O(log2(n)) would be fewer steps than O(1) (constant 32 steps). It's not clear to me if the OP is considering the case where 1000 bytes is a constant, or just an example of a possible value for n.

Comment: @rcgldr It was just an example. It could be an unbounded number of zeros.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Your comments were rather helpful combined with the answers.

Comment: @MikeMarynowski - I updated my answer, with example code (I thought I had done this before). The time complexity can be reduced to O(1) by using a table lookup to generate constants of the form pow(2,8*i)%polynomial for i = 1 to n. Then to handle 1 to n zero bytes a table lookup is done, followed by a software carryless multiply % polynomial (32 iterations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the result of applying *n* zeros not in O(1) time, but in O(log *n*) time. This is done in zlib's `crc32_combine()`. A binary matrix is constructed that represents the operation of applying a single zero bit to the CRC. The 32x32 matrix multiplies the 32-bit CRC over GF(2), where addition is replaced by exclusive-or (^) and multiplication is replaced by and (&), bit by bit.

Then that matrix can be squared to get the operator for two zeros. That is squared to get the operator for four zeros. The third one is squared to get the operator for eight zeros. And so on as needed.

Now that set of operators can be applied to the CRC based on the one bits in the number *n* of zero bits that you want to compute the CRC of.

You can precompute the resulting matrix operator for any number of zero bits, if you happen to know you will be frequently applying exactly that many zeros. Then it is just one matrix multiplication by a vector, which is in fact O(1).

You do not need to use the `pclmulqdq` instruction suggested in another answer here, but that would be a little faster if you have it. It would not change the O() of the operation.

Comment: The mention of `pclmulqdq` in my answer was for a fast crc32 with non-zero data. I updated my answer to make that clear.

Comment: I updated my answer to note time complexity of O(1) is possible using a table lookup and a software based carryless multiply modulo crc polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Time complexity can be reduced to O(1) using a table lookup followed by a multiply. The explanation and example code are shown in the third section of this answer.

If the 1000 is a constant, a precomputed table of 32 values, each representing 
each bit of a CRC to 8000th power mod poly could be used. A set of matrices (one set per byte of the CRC) could be used to work with a byte at a time. Both methods would be constant time (fixed number of loops) O(1).

As commented above, if the 1000 is not a constant, then exponentiation by squaring could be used which would be O(log2(n)) time complexity, or a combination of precomputed tables for some constant number of zero bits, such as 256, followed by exponentiation by squaring could be used so that the final step would be O(log2(n%256)).

---

Optimization in general: for normal data with zero and non-zero elements, on an modern X86 with pclmulqdq (uses xmm registers), a fast crc32 (or crc16) can be implemented, although it's close to 500 lines of assembly code. Intel document: [crc using pclmulqdq](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-crc-computation-generic-polynomials-pclmulqdq-paper.pdf). Example source code for [github fast crc16](https://github.com/01org/isa-l/blob/master/crc/crc16_t10dif_01.asm). For a 32 bit CRC, a different set of constants is needed. If interested, I converted the source code to work with Visual Studio ML64.EXE (64 bit MASM), and created examples for both left and right shift 32 bit CRC's, each with two sets of constants for the two most popular CRC 32 bit polynomials (left shift polys: crc32:0x104C11DB7 and crc32c: 0x11EDC6F41, right shift poly's are bit reversed).

---

Example code for fast adjustment of CRC using a software based carryless multiply modulo the CRC polyonomial. This will be much faster than using a 32 x 32 matrix multiply. A CRC is calculated for non-zero data: crf = GenCrc(msg, ...). An adjustment constant is calculated for n zero bytes: pmc = pow(2^(8*n))%poly (using exponentiation by repeated squaring). Then the CRC is adjusted for the zero bytes: crf = (crf*pmc)%poly.

Note that time complexity can be reduced to O(1) with generation of a table of pow(2^(8*i))%poly constants for i = 1 to n. Then the calculation is a table lookup and a fixed iteration (32 cycles) multiply % poly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char       uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;

static uint32_t crctbl[256];

void GenTbl(void)                       /* generate crc table */
{
uint32_t crc;
uint32_t c;
uint32_t i;
    for(c = 0; c < 0x100; c++){
        crc = c<<24;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            crc = (crc<<1)^((0-(crc>>31))&0x04c11db7);
        crctbl[c] = crc;
    }
}

uint32_t GenCrc(uint8_t * bfr, size_t size) /* generate crc */
{
uint32_t crc = 0u;
    while(size--)
        crc = (crc<<8)^crctbl[(crc>>24)^*bfr++];
    return(crc);
}

/* carryless multiply modulo crc */
uint32_t MpyModCrc(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) /* (a*b)%crc */
{
uint32_t pd = 0;
uint32_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        pd = (pd<<1)^((0-(pd>>31))&0x04c11db7u);
        pd ^= (0-(b>>31))&a;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return pd;
}

/* exponentiate by repeated squaring modulo crc */
uint32_t PowModCrc(uint32_t p)          /* pow(2,p)%crc */
{
uint32_t prd = 0x1u;                    /* current product */
uint32_t sqr = 0x2u;                    /* current square */
    while(p){
        if(p&1)
            prd = MpyModCrc(prd, sqr);
        sqr = MpyModCrc(sqr, sqr);
        p >>= 1;
    }
    return prd;
}

/* # data bytes */
#define DAT  ( 32)
/* # zero bytes */
#define PAD  (992)
/* DATA+PAD */
#define CNT (1024)

int main()
{
uint32_t pmc;
uint32_t crc;
uint32_t crf;
uint32_t i;
uint8_t *msg = malloc(CNT);

    for(i = 0; i < DAT; i++)           /* generate msg */
        msg[i] = (uint8_t)rand();
    for( ; i < CNT; i++)
        msg[i] = 0;
    GenTbl();                           /* generate crc table */
    crc = GenCrc(msg, CNT);             /* generate crc normally */
    crf = GenCrc(msg, DAT);             /* generate crc for data */
    pmc = PowModCrc(PAD*8);             /* pmc = pow(2,PAD*8)%crc */
    crf = MpyModCrc(crf, pmc);          /* crf = (crf*pmc)%crc */
    printf("%08x %08x\n", crc, crf);    /* crf == crc */
    free(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On modern CPUs, fast crc32 (and 8, and 16, and 64) is already implemented in hardware. Exactly 1 line of assembly code: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=crc32&expand=1281,1281

Comment: @Soonts - That instruction only works for right shifting crc32c (a specific polynomial).

Comment: Might be good enough for the op. The instruction is very fast, 1000 values = less than 1 microsecond, barely measurable.

Comment: @Soonts - if the OP is using a different polynomial, or is using a left shifting CRC, then that instruction won't help. Even if the OP is using a right shifting crc32c, it's not that much faster, on my system, Intel 3770K 3.5 ghz, for 256 MB , pclmulqdq => 0.0783919 sec, crc32 intrinsic => 0.0541801 sec. Although it's 500 lines versus 1 line of code.

Answer (score 0):

CRC32 is based on multiplication in GF(2)[X] modulo some polynomial, which is multiplicative. Tricky part is splitting the non-multiplicative from the multiplicative.

First define a sparse file with the following structure (in Go):

```golang
type SparseFile struct {
    FileBytes []SparseByte
    Size      uint64
}
type SparseByte struct {
    Position uint64
    Value    byte
}
```

In your case it would be `SparseFile{[]FileByte{}, 1000}`

Then, the function would be:

```
func IEEESparse (file SparseFile) uint32 {
    position2Index := map[uint64]int{}
    for i , v := range(file.FileBytes) {
        file.FileBytes[i].Value = bits.Reverse8(v.Value)
        position2Index[v.Position] = i
    }
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        index, ok := position2Index[uint64(i)]
        if !ok {
            file.FileBytes = append(file.FileBytes, SparseByte{Position: uint64(i), Value: 0xFF})
        } else {
            file.FileBytes[index].Value ^= 0xFF
        }
    }

    // Add padding
    file.Size += 4
    newReminder := bits.Reverse32(reminderIEEESparse(file))

    return newReminder ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
}
```

So note that:

1. Division is performed on bits in the opposite order (per byte).
2. First four bytes are xored with 0xFF.
3. File is padded with 4 bytes.
4. Reminder is reversed again.
5. Reminder is xored again.

The inner function `reminderIEEESparse` is the true reminder and it is easy to implement it in `O(log n)` where n is the size of the file.

You can find a full implementation [here](https://github.com/furstenheim/sparse_crc32).